# What did Thanos save this character from?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos mentions that he saves Gamora, I was wondering what exactly he meant by this.

Was he referring to saving her planet as a whole, did he save her from being chosen to be executed or was she already chosen and then saved by Thanos?

When watching, I wasn't able to tell which side she was originally on.

Comment: Thanos believes the universe is in dire condition, and needs saving. This is his rationale for killing half the population, and is why he believes that he "saved" Gamora (when really, according to her, they were happy and didn't need saving).

Comment: @Charles, psst.  Spoken like someone who think Thanos did something wrong.

Comment: @user1717828 Lol.. it's funny though, because in an interview, Kevin Feige mentioned that sometimes he considers Thanos to be the good guy. I think that, given the events on Vormir w.r.t. Thanos and Gamora, Thanos actually is genuine in his words/ideals; otherwise, the universe wouldn't have rewarded his sacrifice with the soul stone. So, yeah, Thanos truly believes he's on a righteous path. I guess it's whichever side of the fence you fall on..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was in the same discussion. The conversation was:

> **Gamora:** I was a child when you took me.
>
> **Thanos:** I saved you.
>
> **Gamora:** No, no, we were happy on my home planet.
>
> **Thanos:** Going to bed hungry, scrounging for scraps? Your planet was on the brink of collapse. I was the one who stopped that. You know
>   what's happened since then? The children born have known nothing but
>   full bellies and clear skies. It's a paradise.
>
> **Gamora:** Because you murdered half the planet!
>
> **Thanos:** A small price to pay for salvation.
>
> **Gamora:** You're insane. - [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/quotes/qt3943022?mavIsAdult=false&mavCanonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt4154756%2Fquotes)

He saved her from her planet's collapse. According to Thanos her planet was on the brink of collapse. And he saved her from that future by killing half of the life on that planet. That planet is now a paradise because of him.

Answer (score 5):

From what I can remember, he saved her from the culling of her planet by Thanos' army, and that's what he meant.

At this moment, she was looking for her parents, so she wasn't at Thanos' side yet. This is at this very moment he took her with him.

Later on, Thanos speaks of Gamora's homeworld, and how it is now a great place which benefits from the culling.